# Xcode 6 ( beta 1 ) bug with Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a `Single view application` project called "`SpaceImpactSwift`" when I run the app the iPhone simulator is black and the log says:

```
Unknown class _TtC16SpaceImpactSwift18GameViewController in Interface Builder file.
Unknown class SKView in Interface Builder file.
```

Now, it says a SKView is wrong or something, but this is not a SpriteKit project, I had a project called the same that DID use SpriteKi but I removed it and created this.

I have tried `[cmd]+[shift]+K` Clean but it doesn't work.

Comment: Update Xcode to the current beta. Sticking with a beta when a new one is released is kind of asking for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reset the simulator.
2. If it does not work, update to latest **Xcode 6 Beta**.

Comment: Im guessing its just some file error but I dont know where to find it. I sholdnt need to update to latest

Comment: It's recommended that you stay up-to-date with your xCode version, Swift specifications may vary.

Comment: I made it work by deleting derived data, restarting xcode and resetting simulator and restarting.